# Verilog: wait for module logic evaluation in an always block

Tags: verilog, hdl, hardware-design

I want to use the output of another module inside an always block.
Currently the only way to make this code work is by adding **#1** after the *pi_in* assignment so that enough time has passed to allow Pi to finish.

Relevant part from module pLayer.v:

```
Pi pi(pi_in,pi_out);

always @(*)
begin

    for(i=0; i<constants.nSBox; i++) begin
        for(j=0; j<8; j++) begin
            x               = (state_value[(constants.nSBox-1)-i]>>j) & 1'b1;
            pi_in           = 8*i+j;#1; /* wait for pi to finish */
            PermutedBitNo   = pi_out;
            y               = PermutedBitNo>>3;

            tmp[(constants.nSBox-1)-y] ^= x<<(PermutedBitNo-8*y);
        end
    end
    state_out = tmp;
end
```

Modllue Pi.v

```
`include "constants.v" 

module Pi(in, out);
input  [31:0]   in;
output [31:0]   out;
reg [31:0] out;

always @* begin
    if (in != constants.nBits-1) begin
        out = (in*constants.nBits/4)%(constants.nBits-1);
    end else begin
        out = constants.nBits-1;
    end
end
endmodule
```

Delays should not be used in the final implementation, so is there another way without using **#1**?

In essence i want **PermutedBitNo = pi_out** to be evaluated only after the Pi module has finished its job with pi_in (=8*i+j) as input.
How can i block this line until Pi has finished?

Do i have to use a clock? If that's the case, please give me a hint.

**update:**

Based on Krouitch suggestions i modified my modules. Here is the updated version:

From pLayer.v:

```
    Pi pi(.clk (clk),
      .rst (rst),
      .in  (pi_in),
      .out (pi_out));

counter c_i (clk, rst, stp_i, lmt_i, i);
counter c_j (clk, rst, stp_j, lmt_j, j);

always @(posedge clk)
begin
    if (rst) begin
        state_out = 0;
    end else begin
        if (c_j.count == lmt_j) begin
            stp_i = 1;
        end else begin
            stp_i = 0;
        end

        // here, the logic starts
        x               = (state_value[(constants.nSBox-1)-i]>>j) & 1'b1;
        pi_in           = 8*i+j;
        PermutedBitNo   = pi_out;
        y               = PermutedBitNo>>3;
        tmp[(constants.nSBox-1)-y] ^= x<<(PermutedBitNo-8*y);

        // at end
        if (i == lmt_i-1)
            if (j == lmt_j) begin
                state_out = tmp;
            end
    end
end
endmodule

module counter(
  input  wire clk,
  input  wire rst,
  input  wire stp,
  input  wire [32:0] lmt,
  output reg  [32:0] count
);

always@(posedge clk or posedge rst)
    if(rst)
        count <= 0;
    else if (count >= lmt)
        count <= 0;
    else if (stp)
        count <= count + 1;
endmodule
```

From Pi.v:

```
always @* begin
    if (rst == 1'b1) begin
        out_comb = 0;
    end
    if (in != constants.nBits-1) begin
        out_comb = (in*constants.nBits/4)%(constants.nBits-1);
    end else begin
        out_comb = constants.nBits-1;
    end
end

always@(posedge clk) begin
    if (rst)
        out <= 0;
    else
        out <= out_comb;
end
```

Answer (score 3):

That's a nice piece of software you have here...

The fact that this language describes hardware is not helping then.

In verilog, what you write will simulate in zero time. it means that your loop on `i` and `j` will be completely done in zero time too. That is why you see something when you force the loop to wait for 1 time unit with `#1`.

So yes, **you have to use a clock**.

For your system to work you will have to implement counters for `i` and `j` as I see things.

A counter synchronous counter with reset can be written like this:

```
`define SIZE 10
module counter(
  input  wire clk,
  input  wire rst_n,
  output reg [`SIZE-1:0] count
);

always@(posedge clk or negedge rst_n)
  if(~rst_n)
    count <= `SIZE'd0;
  else
    count <= count + `SIZE'd1;
endmodule
```

You specify that you want to sample `pi_out` only when `pi_in` is processed.
In a digital design it means that you want to wait one clock cycle between the moment when you are sending `pi_in` and the moment when you are reading `pi_out`.

The best solution, in my opinion, is to make your `pi` module sequential and then consider `pi_out` as a register.

To do that I would do the following:

```
module Pi(in, out);
input           clk;
input  [31:0]   in;
output [31:0]   out;
reg [31:0]  out;
wire        clk;
wire [31:0] out_comb;
always @* begin
  if (in != constants.nBits-1) begin
    out_comb = (in*constants.nBits/4)%(constants.nBits-1);
  end else begin
    out_comb = constants.nBits-1;
  end
end

always@(posedge clk)
  out <= out_comb;

endmodule
```

Quickly if you use counters for `i` and `j` and this last `pi` module this is what will happen:

1. at a new clock cycle, `i` and `j` will change --> `pi_in` will change accordingly at the same time(in simulation)
2. at the next clock cycle `out_comb` will be stored in `out` and then you will have the new value of `pi_out` one clock cycle later than `pi_in`

**EDIT**

First of all, when writing (synchronous) processes, I would advise you to deal only with 1 register by process. It will make your code clearer and easier to understand/debug.

Another tip would be to separate combinatorial circuitry from sequential. It will also make you code clearer and understandable.

If I take the example of the counter I wrote previously it would look like :

```
`define SIZE 10
module counter(
  input  wire clk,
  input  wire rst_n,
  output reg [`SIZE-1:0] count
);

//Two way to do the combinatorial function
//First one
wire [`SIZE-1:0] count_next;
assign count_next = count + `SIZE'd1; 

//Second one  
reg [`SIZE-1:0] count_next;
always@*
  count_next = count + `SIZE'1d1;


always@(posedge clk or negedge rst_n)
  if(~rst_n)
    count <= `SIZE'd0;
  else
    count <= count_next;


endmodule
```

Here I see why you have one more cycle than expected, it is because you put the combinatorial circuitry that controls your `pi` module in you synchronous process. It means that the following will happen :

1. first `clk` positive edge `i` and `j` will be evaluated
2. next cycle, the `pi_in` is evaluated
3. next cycle, `pi_out` is captured

So it makes sense that it takes 2 cycles.

To correct that you should take out of the synchronous process the 'logic' part. As you stated in your commentaries it is logic, so it should not be in the synchronous process.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, your tips got me one step further.
However, now i have the problem that out_comb is always not one, but (for some reason) two cycles later.
so when i want to use PermuteBitNo in tmp it returns incorrect results.

Comment: Note that out_comb had to be a reg because its assigned in an always block. Also i'm not sure why you used a negated resets. Is there a specific reason?

Comment: I am sure of the profound justification but I think I read that it has something to do with the early stages of digital electronics with TTL designs where having a low-level reset was justified for power consumption considerations. However in all the designs that I worked with that is the way we do it. I guess it became sort of a convention to do it that way. You can post a question on SO (or maybe more on http://electronics.stackexchange.com) about that. I am sure there is someone more aware about that out there.